# How to repair rubber welly boots?

Tags: boots, waterproofing, repairs

I have a pair of wellington boots (aka rainboots or gumboots), they are now a few years old and getting a bit worn out. They have a few small punctures in them, and are splitting where they bend at the toes. So this means water can leak in.

What is the best way to repair the holes, and restore their waterproofing? Some sort of glue or rubber cement? Or maybe a bicycle puncture repair kit?

Answer (score 8):

My personal recommendation would be to use Super/Krazy Glue for any small "cracks" in the rubber.  I have successfully used it on rubber and it is quite effective!

for the slightly larger holes than cannot be filled using a liquid glue, I would recommend the following:
Apply a Gore-Tex or similar patch along with some "Shoe-Goo" or similar product.  **After you have applied your patch and goo you can always add a layer of super glue over the top for added protection.

I would not recommend using a bicycle tube patch kit as they are very weak and my personal experience with them has only been awful.  I actually now use Krazy Glue on any pinch flats, it has saved me a lot of money and not to mention has worked flawlessly!

If Krazy Glue can hold 110PSI of air inside a thin rubber tube, I am almost positive it will keep the water out of your boots!

**Do not get the Krazy Glue on the Gore-Tex patch, it will destroy it!  Krazy glue can be used on rubber but it will destroy any fluoropolymer such as Gore-Tex!

Answer (score 5):

A temporary fix I have tried while fishing is to use duct tape. just tape on both sides if the hole and it should hold until you can make some more permanent repairs.

To repair damage in a more permanent fashion you can fill the smaller holes with wet-room silicone and then cover the fix with a rubber patch of some description.